# Deploying VS2010 SP1 using .NET 4 bootstrapper

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I recently updated Visual Studio 2010 to SP1 and noticed the .NET 4 framework changed from version "4.0.30319.1" to "4.0.30319.225". I was not able to locate an updated .NET 4 framework installer for "4.0.30319.225". I could only find an update exe which is used to update a particular machine. When I deploy my application now, it still uses the older pre-SP1 version of the framework.

Is there a new bootstrapper that I should be using? Are there any issues with deploying an application that is developed/tested on "4.0.30319.225" to a target machine which only has "4.0.30319.1" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a comment on [Announcing Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2011/03/08/announcing-visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1.aspx) (check page two of the comments) from Jason Zander:

> There have been questions about
>   updates to the .NET Framework.  There
>   is no full service pack for .NET
>   Framework 4.  However there is an
>   update which you can download from
>   here: go.microsoft.com/fwlink.  The
>   outline of fixes (linked from the
>   download page) is here:
>   support.microsoft.com/.../2468871.
>
> This update is titled "Microsoft .NET
>   Framework 4 KB2468871".  You can read
>   more about what is in the update on
>   the download page.
>
> As I mentioned in a previous comment,
>   VS2010 SP1 requires this update and
>   will automatically install it as part
>   of setup.
>
> When you build a project using VS2010
>   SP1, it does not force a dependency on
>   the update.  Whether you need to
>   deploy the update with your client or
>   server application depends on your
>   need for the fixes in the update.  You
>   will need to look through what it
>   contains to make that call.

I've personally seen no issue publishing to a server before running the update manually.

I can't speak to the bootstrapper question.